# cannot locate the .lib file VS12 is trying to open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, .lib

So I am creating an app in VS2012 in MFC using an old Microsoft SDK (called VisSDK for machine vision) which worked fine with VS6. The problem is, I get this LNK1104 error, Cannot open file `VisImSrcLibDB.lib`.

I have done a search through the project for `VisImSrcLibDB`...but nothing came up. I have checked all the header files (external) and tried to see where is this being called.
I can presume (based on the name) that it seems to be part of the SDK, but cannot for the love of god figure out where is this being called from.

Any Help would be appreciated in this. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

PS: yes I have mapped the lib folder of the SDK under LINKER properties. and the corresponding  include folder in the Additional Include directory.

Comment: Are you sure the older SDK it already built?

Comment: The thing is the older SDK has been working fine with VS6 for many years. so I dont think the SDK is the problem. I need to figure out where this .lib file or its corresponding .h file is getting called from. Searches come up empty within the project

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you should turn on the VS flags for verbose output.  That should give some indication as to why things are being pulled into the build.

Comment: Still no clarity with regards to figuring out where this .lib is getting called from.

Comment: Actually, I should have been more clear in my comment.  You should try using the "Show Includes" flag of the compiler options.  This will show where the header files for the library are being pulled from.

Answer (score 0):

The VisImSrcLibDB.lib must exist some where in your VisSDK directory.

Use the PROJECT-Properties command, **All configurations** from the **Configuration** drop down list and add the directory containing the VisImSrcLibDB.lib file to the **Library Directories** in the **VC++ Directories** section.

Comment: @ Michael, Thanks but that is the 1st thing I tried doing. I have searched for that file on my machine and on the web with no results.

Comment: Any ways, this will be a mystery, I seem to have gotten rid of the error, by Process of elimination..Commenting out header file calls from within other header files.